# sonata validation of user group not working

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata

i'm using sonata 2.8 with fos user bundle, i extends user entity and admin, and it woks everythings except a validation of user group.

i would an inline error that preventing sending data if an user dosn't have almost a group selected, is possible?

i already tried with

```
->add('groups', 'sonata_type_model', array(
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'required'    => true
                ))
```

but deosn't works

the problem appears in every field with relationship many to one or many to many, for example i have a 2 entity paese , zone, with

```
// paeseAdmin.php

$formMapper
        ->with('Zone')
            ->add('name', 'text' , array('label'=>"Paese"))
            ->add('zone','sonata_type_collection',array('by_reference' => false, 'required' => true,), array( 'edit' => 'inline','inline' => 'table', 'class' => 'test',))

        ->end() 
    ;

// paese  entity
/**
* @var Zona
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Zona", mappedBy="paesi" ,  orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\OrderBy({"nome" = "ASC"})
*/
private $zone;



// zona entity
/**
 * @var Paese
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Paese", inversedBy="zone" )
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"nome" = "ASC"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="paese_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $paesi;
```

any ideas? thank you

Answer (score 2):

**If you're using Sonata Admin bundle**, you may use `validate` inherited function in order to proceed advanced validations (such as collection counting)

For example:

```php
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\CoreBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;

class UserAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{

    /// ...

    public function validate(ErrorElement $errorElement, $object)
    {
        if (!$object->getGroups()->count()) {
            $errorElement
                ->with('groups')
                ->addViolation('You should select at least one group')
                ->end();
        }

        parent::validate($errorElement, $object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The documentation doesn't mention this

Answer (score 0):

You have `'required' => false` and then `'required' => true` you need to remove the extra one

From the sonata doc on sonata type collection

> Setting the ‘required’ option to true does not cause a requirement of ‘at least one’ child entity. Setting the ‘required’ option to false causes all nested form fields to become not required as well.

When you add `required => true` to a `sonata_type_collection` field you only allow having required fields in the child form.

Comment: after removed nothing changed

Comment: If you have `required =>  true` you should be having a tooltip appearing telling you that you have to select an element from the list when you submit the form.Anyways you probably wan't to look at https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle it is made to integrate FOSuser into sonata admin so it should save you some trouble

Comment: i have sonatauserbundle, but i validation still not works

Comment: and the problems is in every field many to one and many to many

Comment: so is impossible validate?

Answer (score 0):

so you must add those lines in your entity User

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;


    /**
     * @Assert\Callback(methods={"isGroupValid"})
     */
     public function isGroupValid(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if ($this->groups->count()==0) {
            $context
                 ->buildViolation('choisir au minimum un group!', array(), null)
                 ->atPath('groups')
                 ->addViolation()`enter code here`;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Version Version of Sonata nothing worked for me.

sonata-project/admin-bundle              3.51.0

friendsofsymfony/user-bundle             v2.1.2

The validate method was not called no matter what.

So I ended up writing a validation:

```
#File: src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Resources/config/validation.xml

    <property name="groups">
        <constraint name="Count">
            <option name="min">1</option>
            <option name="minMessage">Please choose one group.</option>
        </constraint>
    </property>
```